# Has Xcode 6 changed the rules for accessing IBOutlets?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode6, iboutlet

I was under the impression when designing views in IB, you should always make your IBOutlet's weak. In the latest Xcode 6 I have started to get a strange warning on new projects.

[image: Outlet may be set to nil]

This seems new to me, so I decided to try this:

[image: no warning here]

This pattern loosely follows what Apple is having us do with accessing swift optionals. (the if-let pattern)

So, my question is:

"What has changed? Should we be making our outlets strong? Maybe we are being nudged into changing our outlet access patterns? or maybe this is just an Xcode 6.1 bug and will be resolved later?"

I am not sure what the solution is and would love to hear discussion on this.

Thanks

**UPDATE:**
Blah, looks like going through the warnings and it looks like the "sending messages to weak pointers" warning was turned on, not sure why, but that was the problem.

Comment: I dont think they changed that but the compiler doesnt really know about outlets and it cannot predict when they are assigned. the warning actually makes sense. you should handle the nil case althought an assert might be simpler. you can also turn off that specific warning.

Comment: I can't reproduce your warning. How have you declared customLabel, and in what kind of class do you have this code?

Comment: I  believe IBOutlets are weak anyway so you don't have to define them as such. Try leaving out (weak)

Comment: It's in a ui table view cell and I dragged out the IBOutlet. I let Xcode specify the weak/strongness

Comment: CustomLabel is a property in the private class extension.

Answer (score 0):

It's generally considered safe to let an `IBOutlet` property be weak if it refers to something in the view hierarchy owned by the nib's main object. In that case, you have a strong reference to the root view of that hierarchy, and that in turn has strong references to all its subviews.

You should use a strong reference instead if, for example, you plan to remove a subviews from that hierarchy and replace it later/elsewhere.

The compiler can't tell how your nib/storyboard is set up, or know what your plans for an outlet variable might be, so that warning is broadly applied.